# Sending Push/Update notifications to an Application via Python?

Tags: android, python, ios, python-2.7, push-notification

I'm looking to create a simple push notification service for Android & iOS to be able to do some pretty simple tasks..

Sending just pure text to an Application via Python... how would/could this be done?

Could anyone help me with where to start, it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: refer https://github.com/venkatesh22/django-push-notifications

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link https://github.com/dhruvbaldawa/android_gcm

gcm_server.py can be used to send messages to the android application.

Here is the gcm_server.py from the repo. This script needs Google OAuth key. Follow the steps mentioned in the repo

```
from gcm import GCM
import argparse

# API Key for your Google OAuth project
API_KEY = ''


def send_push_notification(registration_id, message):
    gcm = GCM(API_KEY)
    resp = gcm.plaintext_request(registration_id=registration_id,
                                 data={'message': message})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--reg-id', dest='registration_id', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--message', dest='message', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    send_push_notification(args.registration_id, args.message)
```